# Javascript (react) calculator depends on in between values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, calculator, distance

I'm trying to make a simple(probably) react calculator with increasing shipping cost depends on the distance. But I'm literally stacked for now.

Let's say the car will ride every time from the city center to the outskirts. The car will take a package from starting point and deliver it to ending point. The farther from the city, the higher the price per 1 mile\km.

My variables: x: starting point, y: ending point, n: cost per 1 mile\km (n = 1,2,3 just for a better explanation so n+1 will not work here, later I want to change it into .24 cents\points or whatever)

Expected results:

example: if x = 10, y = 25 then cost = 30 $ \ points \ whatever (5 + 10 + 15 => because between (
5 and 15) n = 1, between (
15 and 20) n = 2 and between (
20 and 25) n = 3 ..and so on if we will take a longer distance)

Actual results: depends on <= and && or || statements inside "if" the cost is calculating..

1st example: depends on higher price (n), so the player will be charged for.. like he is started from higher, most valuable distance (if x = 10, y = 25 then cost = 45 because n between 20 and 25 = 3)

2nd ex: depends on lower price (x = 10, y = 25 => cost = 15)

Probably I'm missing something with react or maybe some math logic but can't realize what exactly I need to do and I wasted so much time on this part of my pet-proj, so for the first time ever I'm asking for help :) Thanks for advance!

Also I didn't get why should I need sometimes to click on button twice for useState update..

My code sandbox for you https://codesandbox.io/s/distance-react-calc-on-states-rjuek

If u'd like to see the code here:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [x, setX] = useState(5);
  const [y, setY] = useState(10);
  const [n, setN] = useState(null); // n - the cost value per 1 mile/km
  const [total, setTotal] = useState((y - x) * n);

  function calculateTotal() {
    if (x <= 5 && y < 15) {
      setN(1);
      setTotal((y - x) * n);
    } else if (x <= 15 && y < 20) {
      setN(2);
      setTotal((y - x) * n);
    } else if (x <= 20 && y <= 25) {
      setN(3);
      setTotal((y - x) * n);
    } else if (x <= 25 && y < 30) {
      setN(4);
      setTotal((y - x) * n);
    } else if (30 <= x && y < 35) {
      setN(5);
      setTotal((y - x) * n);
    } else if (35 <= x && y < 40) {
      setN(6);
      setTotal((y - x) * n);
    }
    return calculateTotal;
  }

  return (
    <div className="Calc">
      <div className="number-inputs">
        <input
          type="number"
          step="1"
          value={x}
          onChange={(e) => setX(+e.target.value)}
        />
        <input
          type="number"
          step="1"
          value={y}
          onChange={(e) => setY(+e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>

      <button onClick={calculateTotal}>Calc</button>

      <h2 id="currentDistance">{total}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: `return calculateTotal;` isn't probably what you mean. also you do not need state for `n` (and that's why changes won't be visible immediately)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 setN(1);
 setTotal((y - x) * n)
```

React works with the idea of virtual DOM, therefore even if you place above two set functions one after the other, by the time `setTotal((y - x) * n)` executes `n` value might be of the previous state that is `null`. This is the reason for you need to press the button twice.

So write any logic that uses `setState` assuming that you will not get that value immediately in preceding statements.

Ex:

```
 setN(1);
 setTotal((y - x) * 1)
```

Comment: ty for help about useState problem!